# How to optimize Javascript lookups?

Tags: javascript

According to Javascript's major implementations, the lookup for variables and functions starts at the spot and traversing upwards until the global objects.

Now lets say you're building larger OOP based frameworks and you need to call safety checks all over the place, then it doesnt seem right to call those things that way : "xapp.utils.isValidString(var). The same applies to constants, enumerations and flags which take place everywhere usally.

I am not quite sure whether this has impacts on the answer but we're doing all in Dojo and we are pretty aware about its lang.mixin method.

However, the idea is to mixin an obvious and minimal set of functions and objects into the target objects local scope by using the constructor or prototype. Would you consider this to be a legal way ?

Then what about caching and reusing those prepared objects ? Which kind of buffer you would choose ? To me it looks rather like an ring buffer.

I am still learning JS optimization and I would be happy about your thoughts !

For your reference, here some common tips about scope managment explained by a guru : http://googlecode.blogspot.com.es/2009/06/nicholas-c-zakas-speed-up-your.html

Update : We need to focus only on modern desktop and mobile browsers, leaving IE totally out !
Also, we're familiar with Dojo's build chain, enabling conditional compiling per platform (If that matters).

Comment: Tip: Optimize only when you have to. Don't be lazzy, but don't be mad about performace until you can have any measure.

Comment: Thanks we seriously have to because we're dealing with serveral layered Dojo apps having some MB final code size and it becomes noticable slower over the last years.

Comment: The question is if that article is valid now with the new JS engines all browsers have implemented since then. Jit compiling and better parser optimizations might have changes the playing field, the article is 3 years and many many browser version old.

Comment: One thing we found out is that many solutions rebuilds events to often and many also fail to kill old events causing multiple instances of the same event fireing on one trigger, at least in some browsers and versions.

Comment: What are your target platform, is it older IE or only more modern browsers?

Comment: We need to deal with all desktop and mobile browsers except IE. We are familar with conditional compiling as done in the Dojo build chain tools, so we can do pretty much that way. So, yes its only for modern browsers, I guess.

Comment: Found this more recent lists: http://www.techhui.com/profiles/blogs/front-end-optimization-tips-1, http://jonraasch.com/blog/10-javascript-performance-boosting-tips-from-nicholas-zakas. But I think you should really think on what and why things are slow before trying to optimize code.

Comment: Thank you. You're right, we do have enough other bottlenecks to solve but we'd like to make sure that we did best or at least good in all aspects as we face large pieces of nested OOP code.

Comment: why dont the dojo AMD work for you?

Comment: @VEXii : no, its not really Dojo related.

Comment: @mc007: you sure? becouse whith the AMD you can just require code in and scooping + look up is done? or is the require name getting to long?

Comment: yes, sure. if you look at the resolver and their own recommendations, leave the mixin/amd feature better as build friendly profiles/helpers. But I agree, it de-mangles a lot of namespacing already but has plenty of other side effects, especially dynamic build-variables are a pain to do there surprisingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for identifier resolution, i.e. direct references, I recommend that you switch to the strict language (if you already haven't), a.k.a. "strict mode". The strict language is statically scoped, which enables JS engines to statically bind the identifiers, which results in better performance during program execution (the identifiers have already been bound during compilation).

---

As for property look-ups, if you have long chains, e.g.

```
foo.bar.baz.method1();
foo.bar.baz.method2();
```

the usual solution (not just for performance, but also to avoid code repetition) is to store the right-most object into a local variable:

```
var baz = foo.bar.baz;

baz.method1();
baz.method2();
```

Comment: sounds great ! I will run some tests with this. thank you for now !

Comment: Sime: Does this type of "caching" things in local variables make a measurable difference?

Comment: @Richard No. But the code repetition that is avoided is reason enough to do it.